# Should we create a wish-list tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I know that its not the scope of this forum, but I see some answers being provided by developers of the said applications, and it would be a good place for the average user to post them, and another place for developers to look for improvements. Many average users cant go through the process of creating a wish-list, for the simple reason that it might be too complicated/difficult.

Appreciate your time,

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No

It's out of the scope of the FAQ, and the Bug Tracker of the app in question is, and probably will be for some time, the correct place to put wishlist bugs. The problem with wishlist bugs is that they have no answer, in general.

Oh and there's [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) as well. :-)

As far as I can tell, wishlist bugs can be devided into two categories:

- "Please improve feature X", "Add plugin Y" and so on

  These are only interesting to the developers, they are **too localised** for the general audience of the internet.

  and
- "Clock should be in the bottom right corner, not the top left"

  These are conceptual and more general. They involve multiple projects and are generally  approved or rejected by, say the UX team or the Server team, because they change the *architecture*. Those belong on Brainstorm, they are **not real questions**, they have no answer, not even by any one developer.

> Many average users cant go through the process of creating a wish-list, for the simple reason that it might be too complicated/difficult.

You're completely right, and it's a good idea. But it's not going to work. We should embrace the existing technologies in this case. Though I think Brainstorm could use a new lick of paint. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This would be far outside the scope of the site; I suggest you leave feature requests in the bug / work item trackers of the respective projects, instead. That would be more effective.